# If $M$ has only two definable subsets, must it have a transitive automorphism group?

Tags: model-theory

I was told that a sufficient condition for a structure $M$ to have only the empty set and $M$ itself as parameter-free definable subsets, is for $M$ to have a transitive automorphism group. Is the converse true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not - there can be obstacles to transitivity which are "invisible to first-order logic."

The simplest example is probably just a structure $M$ consisting of an equivalence relation with two classes, one of which is countably infinite and the other of which is uncountable.

- By downwards Lowenheim-Skolem, $M$ has a countable elementary substructure $M_0$; it's not hard to show that $M_0$'s automorphism group acts transitively.
- That means that $M_0$ has no nontrivial definable sets, which by elementarity means that $M$ doesn't either.
- But $M$'s automorphism group does *not* act transitively: no element of the countable class is automorphic to any element of the uncountable class.

Of course in some sense this is a bit unsatisfying - the reliance on cardinality leaves open the question of whether the same situation can happen with *countable* structures, which - per the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem - is arguably the right question. It turns out this still happens for countable structures, although less trivially. In my opinion, the most satisfying argument is the following:

Given linear orders $A,B$, let $AB$ be the linear order consisting of "$B$-many copies of $A$." Specifically, $AB$ has domain $A\times B$ and is ordered via $$\langle a,b\rangle\le \langle c,d\rangle\iff b<d\vee (b=d\wedge a\le c).$$

- What can you say about the definable sets in $\mathbb{Z}B$ for *any* linear order $B$? *(A good tool for this is Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games.)*
- Can you find a linear order $B$ such that $\mathbb{Z}B$'s automorphism group does not act transitively?  *(HINT: think about what the transitivity of the action of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}B)$ on $\mathbb{Z}B$ would imply about the action of $Aut(B)$ on $B$.)*

Comment: Sorry. I do not know about Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games, and I can't find such a linear order.

Comment: @user107952 Let's focus on the second part first. What's the simplest nontrivial linear order you know?

Comment: The order {(0,1}} on two elements.

Comment: @user107952 Great - now does the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}{\bf 2}=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$ act transitively? (I'm using the notation "${\bf n}$" for the unique-up-to-isomorphism linear order with $n$ elements - this is fairly standard in my experience.)

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @user107952 Well there you go - $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$ has a nontransitive automorphism group action, but you can show that it also has no nontrivial parameter-freely-definable subsets.